# How do I find a file by filename in pycharm IDE?

Tags: pycharm

Sometimes when working on a large codebase one may have difficulty finding a file mentioned in a stack trace. How does one search for that file without manually looking in every directory and without making a script to do it?

Comment: A note: I'm assuming that this question is on-topic as it qualifies as under "Software development tools." If it's not we may just want to move it to Super User

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Pycharm IDE do `Ctrl+Shift+N` and you will see a popup menu that lets you select "file" then type to search for files matching your query.

[Source](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Part+1.+Finding+a+file%2C+class.+or+symbol+by+name)

Comment: if you use Mac the keys for "Go to file" command are `Command+Shift+O`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using macOS, it's `Cmd + Shift + O` .